# (Javascript) Alternative to "event.returnValue" in "beforeunload" event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

We have a scenario where we need to prevent window/tab close and show a confirm dialog with browser default prompt message.

Mozilla doc says use `Event.preventDefault()` instead of `Event.returnValue` please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue

What I found is `Event.preventDefault()` is working as expected i.e. preventing tab close in Safari and Firefox whereas in Chrome it is not. Do we have any alternative to this or any suggestions?

Please note they mentioned we need to use `Event.returnValue` in Chrome/chromium browsers refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: Detect the browser using javascript and apply logic based on that.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is "onBeforeUnload". It doesn't really prevent default, you can do actions for it.

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit() {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
}
```

Not sure if it's what you are looking for, but it might connect something up.

Some explaining. [source](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm)

It does cancel exit if he clicks cancel.

EDIT:

Seems like there are folks sayng it didint work, as I've read around, this event was implemented by MS for some browsers, but it was not extended to other sources.

The alternative would be to use

```js
    function unloadPage() {
       alert("unload event detected!");
    }
    window.onunload = unloadPage;
```

Both functions are doc'ed at Firefox doc's

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

While unload event is more widely used as I assumed, in compatibility section that all browsers do support it trough specific versions.

Comment: But it is not preventing the window to close, chrome window/tab getting closed still

Comment: I dont really think that it's possible such thing, maybe I just don't know about it. You could try playing with the alert box and then use .close(); to close it down, the alert box would get clicked by script.

Comment: Hey Man, your solution worked for chrome, safari and Firefox. Thanks. I don't know who gave -1 to you here, you deserve +5. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad I could help. :)

Comment: as of today it doesn't work in chrome

Comment: `onbeforeunload` does not appear to be an actual event, despite references to it on sites here and there